# showing form result in popup window

Tags: javascript

how to show the result of First name and email in popup window.open.
example :

Congratulations!

Name :

EMail :

```js
function validateForm()
    {
        var ufname=document.forms["regform"]["fname"].value;
        var uemail=document.forms["regform"]["email"].value;
        if (ufname=="" || uemail=="")
        {
            alert("PLEASE ENTER THE VALUES!");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<form method="post" name="regform" id="regform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <label>First name </label>
  <input  type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Your Name">
  <label>Email Address </label>
  <input  type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="hi@domain.com">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Register</button>  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: do you want to show alert or modal popup

Comment: There are no `window.open` in your code! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Modal alert if form empty and popup window if submit successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do with new window try this by using `window.open`

```js
function validateForm()
    {
        var ufname=document.forms["regform"]["fname"].value;
        var uemail=document.forms["regform"]["email"].value;
        if (ufname=="" || uemail=="")
        {
            alert("PLEASE ENTER THE VALUES!");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var myWindow = window.open("", "RegisterWindow", "width=200,height=100");
            myWindow.document.write("<p>Congratulations! </p> <p>Name :  "+ufname+".</p><p>EMail : "+ uemail +".");
        }
    }
```

```html
<form method="post" name="regform" id="regform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <label>First name </label>
  <input  type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Your Name">
  <label>Email Address </label>
  <input  type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="hi@domain.com">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Register</button>  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 function validateForm()
    {
        var ufname=document.forms["regform"]["fname"].value;
        var uemail=document.forms["regform"]["email"].value;
        if (ufname=="" || uemail=="")
        {
            alert("PLEASE ENTER THE VALUES!");
            return false;
        } else {
           var popupWindow = window.open('');
           popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '<div>Your Name: '+ufname+'</div><div>Your Email: '+uemail+'</div>'
        }
    }
```